# Batching GL_POLYGON using vertex arrays in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I have a bunch of GL_POLYGONS I need to render using vertex arrays (which are put into Vertex Buffer Objects).

I am using indexing and glDrawElements().

I am aware that you can batch GL_TRIANGLE_STRIPS using redundant vertices, so they are linked up during rendering.

Is something similar possible with GL_POLYGON?

If possible, I would like to avoid calling glDrawElements() in a loop, specifying indices for each polygon.

(This is not for OpenGL ES - I am using OpenGL on a laptop.)

**Edit #1:**

I want to add here that Tim's answer below (primitive restart) works, but you need remember to enable this mode - something that took me a while to figure out. ie:

```
// enable primitive restart
glEnable(GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART);
```

Comment: Though Tim's answer is correct, as a general advice, don't mess with polygons, they're just rubbish (from days when people thought something beyond a triangle could actually make sense). They need to be convex anyway and are thus usually just implemented as a `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN`. And this in turn is just representable by a list of `GL_TRIANGLES`, which eliminates any need for degenerate vertices and restarts. There is a reason `GL_QUADS` and `GL_POLYGON` have been deprecated, nobody cares about non-triangles. Though primitive_restart with a `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN` might be an option.

Comment: That advice is not always practical. In my case, I need to support a geometry format which could have polygons with N sides - convex, non-convex and with holes. I tessellate the non-convex polygons - maybe I need to tessellate the convex ones as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`glMultiDrawElements`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glMultiDrawElements.xml) if you want to draw multiple polygons with a single draw call. You just pass in an an array of pointers to indexes.

Alternatively, if you're targetting a higher version of OpenGL, you can use something called [`glPrimitiveRestartIndex`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glPrimitiveRestartIndex.xml), which allows you to specify a special index value that restarts the current primitive. So you could define a 'special' index, and then any time you insert that index into your array, the polygon will restart with the next index. This is only core in OpenGL 3+ though.

Comment: glPrimitiveRestartIndex is a great suggestion, but unfortunately it is having no effect for me. The indices are populated correctly, with a 65535 as the "separator", and I call this method right before glDrawElements. But the polygons are all joined up...